# how get coordinate of item in list view?

Tags: android, listview, view, coordinates

I have a **listView** with 10 item, that start from center of page, so first item of list is not at the top of screen, I want to get **position** of first item and when list scrolled up and position of first item get to the top of screen do something, for example toast a message that scroll arrived to the top of page.

so my method was getting coordinate of first item using `listView.getChildAt(0)`
get width and height of this view, but every time it returns null,

**FYI:** my **listView** is in a **viewpager** of a **fragment**, and **listView** has header.

how can I get position of first item to compare it by screen top positions?

Answer (score 0):

### Hope this will help you alot.

getChildAt will give you the individual view of any item in the list. getLocationOnScreen gives raw screen coordinates of a view. getWidth and getHeight will establish your bounding box. getFirstVisiblePosition and getLastVisiblePosition establish indexes in the list to search within.

Comment: I solve my problem with these line of codes:

val firstCell = scoreBoardFragmentListView.getChildAt(0) ?: return
                if (scoreBoardFragmentListView.firstVisiblePosition == 0)
                    rootLayout.alpha = (firstCell.height + firstCell.top) / firstCell.height.toFloat()
                else
                    rootLayout.alpha = 0f

Comment: Yes there are several ways..You may upvote this answer too if its reasonable.